# Use mesh as geometry for curve

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves, curve-modifier

So I have an object and a curve.
I want to place the object along the curve

I mean, the arches i made, I would want them to go around in a circle.
[image]
but the curve only allows to use other curves to form geometry. I can't use the object. How can i get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use the curve modifier:

[image]

Note: your mesh needs a lot of "right" geometry so that it works well.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xE2Znen

Comment: make sure both have the same origin